# Posterior of a Normal distribution

Tags: bayesian, posterior, hierarchical-bayesian

I have a problem obtaining a posterior of a normal multivariate distribution. The problem is as follows: Assuming $ \mathbf{X} \sim N_p (\boldsymbol{\mu}, \boldsymbol{\Sigma}) $, known $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$, I am interested in estimating a posterior for $\boldsymbol{\mu}$. Assuming $\boldsymbol{\mu} \sim N_p(\boldsymbol{\mu}_0, \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_0)$ (conjugate prior), we have that for a sample $\mathbf{X}_1, \cdots, \mathbf{X}_n$ of $\mathbf{X} $,

$$\pi(\boldsymbol{\mu}|\mathbf{X}) \sim N(\boldsymbol{\mu}^*, \boldsymbol{\Sigma}^*),$$

on what, $\boldsymbol{\mu}^* = ( \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_0^{-1} + n\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1} )^{-1}( \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_0^{-1} \boldsymbol{\mu}_0 + n\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}\bar{\mathbf{x}} )$ e $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^* = (\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_0^{-1} + n\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1})^{-1}$.

[enter link description here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior)

However, by simulating this process I am getting some results that I cannot understand.

Considering the case $p = 2$. For $\boldsymbol{\Sigma} = \begin{pmatrix} 
10 & 7.668116 \\
7.668116 & 12 \end{pmatrix}$, when simulating $10000$ observations of the vector $\mathbf{X}$, and obtaining the posteriori mean vector $\mathbf{X}$, I get some results that I cannot understand.

Considering it a priori for $\boldsymbol{\mu} \sim N_2\left( \begin{pmatrix} 25\\ 50 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1000 & 0\\ 0 & 1000 \end{pmatrix} \right)$,

I made a function in R to return the values of the parameters of the posterior

```
library(mvtnorm)

paramPosteriorMu = function(X, Sigma, mu0, Sigma0){
   n = nrow(X)
   SigmaStar = solve( solve(Sigma0) + n*solve(Sigma) )
   muStar = SigmaStar %*% ( solve(Sigma0)%*%mu0 + n*solve(Sigma)%*%colMeans(X) )
   return(list(mu = muStar, Sigma = SigmaStar))
}

#observed data:
Sigma = matrix(c(10, 7.668116, 7.668116, 12), nc = 2)
X = rmvnorm(10000, mean = c(5, 2), sigma = Sigma)

#prior:
mu0 = c(25,50)
Sigma0 = matrix(c(1000, 0, 0, 1000), nc = 2)

#posterior:
paramPosteriorMu(X, Sigma, mu0, Sigma0)
```

In my R I'm getting an answer

```
 $Sigma
              [,1]         [,2]
 [1,] 0.0009999984 0.0007668099
 [2,] 0.0007668099 0.0011999980
```

One question, I am not a specialist in Bayesian inference, why are the sigma values so close to zero?

The Wikipedia, where I got the result about a posteriori, says that *"mean was estimated from observations with total precision (sum of all individual precisions) ${\displaystyle {\boldsymbol {\Sigma }}_{0}^{-1}}$ and with sample mean ${\displaystyle {\boldsymbol {\mu }}_{0}}$"*

Is there a misunderstanding in the implementation? Or some error in my understanding?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I just implemented this in Python and I'm getting `[5.01707524, 2.05052953]` as the mean, which seems right.
Maybe try a scatter plot of $X$, and inspect the `colMeans` to see if those are what you expect.

Comment: @RobbytheBelgian, I made a mistake and for the vector of means it is apparently ok, however the covariance matrix shows this result. What is going on?

Comment: We're not estimating the covariance of the sample, but rather the covariance of the mean. The variance of the mean scales by a factor of $\frac{1}{n}$. This is consistent with my results: I took $n = 10,000$ and when I multiply `SigmaStar` by 10,000, I get `Sigma`.